# Cannot write PySpark DF with delta locally

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I'm trying to write a table with delta format on my local machine with the code refer to [Delta documentations](https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html?fbclid=IwAR3-v9nMvTftiA3hxPhR1mggI9HMC2Wx-G5nzj216TCklwLn2G2T6o9cBsM#create-a-table).

```html
import pyspark
from delta import *

builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

stored_path = "E:\tmp\delta.123"
spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
data = spark.range(0, 5)
data.write.format("delta").save(stored_path)

print("============================================================================================")
print("Finish")
print("============================================================================================")
```

But I got this error.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\tests\test_write_delta.py", line 14, in <module>
    data.write.format("delta").save(stored_path)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 968, in save
    self._jwrite.save(path)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o37.save.
: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean 
org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)     
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.getDeltaLogFromCache$1(DeltaLog.scala:604)   
        at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:611)
```

I tried both delta-spark version 2.0.0 and 2.1.0. What's missing here or what is the correct way to run delta on a local project?

Comment: How did you install Hadoop? Looks like your Hadoop version on Windows is different than PySpark expects.

Comment: Quick question, do you get the same error if you were to run this in Parquet (e.g., `data.write.format("parquet").save(stored_path)`.  Concur with @zsxwing call out that this could be related to the Hadoop version as well due to the latest compiled versions of `winutils.exe` are for Hadoop 3.2 while the default for Spark is built for Hadoop 3.3

Comment: Thanks Denny for your help. I got the same error when writing parquet format.